# WYSIWYG editor Angular 6 with link for images

Tags: angular, wysiwyg

Does anyone know an Angular 6 text editor which also has the option to add images by a link? (ex: ngx-editor - this would have worked great except the fact that it depends on rxjs 5 and it is not compatible with rxjs 6). There is an ng6x-editor on npm but it does not work when I try to use it in my app.

Any suggestion would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: What about https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular ? 
The main website is : https://www.tiny.cloud/

Comment: Give a look to [PrimeNg's one](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor), i think it could fit your needs

Comment: @kansen Thanks a lot, works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's wondering, I've gone with @Kansen answer. TinyMCE works perfect